# Why I can't get data from DocumentReference in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a habit contains a reference to an item in categories collection. I want to read data from it.
But it keeps give me an output like this. I've try so many times but I still can't done it:

```
{
    "id": "3TFzK0bvzGsZJyM2IkI2",
    "name": "Pushup",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic ",
    "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f5/46/30/f54630a64c48966b9cf803838c34c313.jpg",
    "categories": {},
    "createdAt": {
        "seconds": 1602046800,
        "nanoseconds": 0
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "id": "3TFzK0bvzGsZJyM2IkI2",
    "name": "Pushup",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic ",
    "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f5/46/30/f54630a64c48966b9cf803838c34c313.jpg",
    "categories": {

    "id": "3TFzK0bvzGsZJyM2IkI2",
    "name": "Pushup",
    "createdAt": {
        "seconds": 1602046800,
        "nanoseconds": 0
    }

},
    "createdAt": {
        "seconds": 1602046800,
        "nanoseconds": 0
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
db.collection("habits")
.get()
.then((data) => {
  let habits = [];
  data.forEach((doc) => {
    let singleRow = doc.data();
    let habit = {
      id: doc.id,
      name: singleRow.name,
      description: singleRow.description,
      imageUrl: singleRow.imageUrl,
      categories: {},
      createdAt: singleRow.createdAt,
    };

    if (singleRow.categories) {
      singleRow.categories
        .get()
        .then((res) => {
          habit.categories = res.data();
          return;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

    habits.push(habit);
  });
  return res.json(habits);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  return res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong...!" });
});
```

Please help me! Thanks alot...!

Comment: What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: I want to have this in categories:
{"id": "3TFzK0bvzGsZJyM2IkI2",
        "name": "Pushup",
        "createdAt": {
            "seconds": 1602046800,
            "nanoseconds": 0
        }}

Comment: Please add it to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

the way this is written, your code will not wait for the promise returned from `singleRow.categories.get()` to resolve before pushing `habit` into `habits` and then returning `res.json(habits)` when the foreach loop completes. Instead, you could use async/await together with `Promise.all` like so:

```js
db.collection("habits")
.get()
.then(async (querySnapshot) => {
  // use Promise.all to wait for all promises in array to resolve or reject.
  const habits = await Promise.all(querySnapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
    // map over data to convert each doc into a promise that will resolve to the value of the habit object.
    const singleRow = doc.data();
    const habit = {
      id: doc.id,
      name: singleRow.name,
      description: singleRow.description,
      imageUrl: singleRow.imageUrl,
      categories: {},
      createdAt: singleRow.createdAt,
    };
    if (singleRow.categories) {
      try {
        // wait for the promise returned from singleRow.categories.get(), then set habit.categories using resolved value
        const res = await singleRow.categories.get()
        habit.categories = res.data();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    return habit
  }))
  return res.json(habits);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  return res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong...!" });
});
```

Comment: I'll edit my answer to give some more detail, stand by...

Comment: it said "data.map is not a function"

Comment: hmm okay it's probably something with the returned value from db.collection('habits').get(). I assumed it was an array since you used `forEach` on it in your question. but maybe there's another step to get the array of documents.

Comment: it looks like db.collection('habits').get() returns a querySnapshot, which you then have to reference .docs on before calling .map. will update my answer to reflect this.